# Saving images to directory using non-local path

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to save an image that is selected by the user to my resources package.  I can only save it by giving a simple path like "title.jpg" or a full local path like "C://res/title.jpg". How can I save to a package?

```
public class ImportFile {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    String fileExtension;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    File file;

    public void chooseFile(){
        extensionFilters();
        file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        try{
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveFile(BufferedImage importedFile, File file,String title) {
        try{
            File saved = new File("\res\"+title+findFileExtension(file));
            ImageIO.write(importedFile,"jpg",saved);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String findFileExtension(File file) {
        String fileName = file.getName();
        fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."), fileName.length());
        return fileExtension;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to save into package in classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following

`File saved = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/<package name>/<filename>.jpg");`

`System.getProperty("user.dir")`: will give the current project directory

`<package name>`: make sure to replace the "." in package name with "/"

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to upload a picture into the package?
Just do not give it a path but just give a name like use file.getOriginalFilename().

have a try? I hope it will help u.
Code:

`if(!file.isEmpty()){
           try {
              BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(file.getOriginalFilename())));
              out.write(file.getBytes());
              out.flush();
              out.close();
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return"failure,"+e.getMessage();
           } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return"failure,"+e.getMessage();
           }
           return"success";
       }else{
           return"the file is  empty";
       }`

Comment: Hello.. welcome to stackoverflow!! please use comment section below if you don't have specific answer of the question otherwise your ans will be down voted by other members. good luck :)